# Workspace switch hot-keys not working in 13.04 (but expo does)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 13.04, workspaces

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 13.04 (through 12.10).  I have re-enabled workspaces in Appearances/Compiz, have a workspace-switcher launcher icon, and can expo with Super-s.  The keyboard shortcuts tab lists Ctrl-Alt-Arrows as the workspace switch shortcuts, but those hot-key combinations don't actually switch my workspaces.

Potentially related: the workspace switcher launcher icon does not accurately reflect windows that are open in workspaces; there is a default-looking two window image that follows the workspace that I'm in regardless of the existence of windows in that or other workspaces.  I don't especially care about this functionality, but if it is supposed to be working and isn't, it might stem from the same problem.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. Please file a bug report. [See, how to file a bug report?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). As such bugs are off topic here. [See FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: I tried to reset the hotkeys, just to be sure. Compiz had <Ctrl><Alt>Left. Trying to reset, compiz interpreted my Ctrl key as being <Primary>. In any case, changing all <Ctrl> instances to <Primary> didn't work either, but it might be a hint as to what went wrong. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: I have not filed a bug report.  If someone else does, that would be great...

Comment: I have this same dang problem. Next stop, bug reports.